# How to change MaxExpansionDepth setting globally in OData

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata, asp.net-core-2.2

I have been looking for a while how to limit `$expand` depth. There is a setting `MaxExpansionDepth` for it but it can be only applied to entity, method or controller. Is there a way to change it globally ?

Comment: It seems that you can set MaxExpansionDepth only in EnableQueryAttribute. But you can create your own attribute with specified value for MaxExpansionDepth